# Is there a way to fix a TCL tkinter error?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I am trying to make a calculator using tkinter python but I am getting an error , I don't know why... This is the code

```
from tkinter import * 

cal = Tk()
cal.title("Calculator")
operator=""
text_Input = StringVar()

txtDisplay = Entry(cal,font=('arial',20,'bold'),textvariable=text_Input , bd=30 , 
                    inserwidth=4 , bg="powder blue", justify='right').grid(columnspan=4)

cal.mainloop()
```

while running it gives this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\User\Desktop\adssib\python\calculator.py", line 9, in <module>
    inserwidth=4 , bg="powder blue", justify='right').grid(columnspan=4)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2676, in __init__
    Widget.__init__(self, master, 'entry', cnf, kw)
  File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2299, in __init__
    (widgetName, self._w) + extra + self._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: unknown option "-inserwidth"
```

can anyone help pls ....

Comment: Change `inserwidth` to `insertwidth`. Spelling mistake?

Comment: Also `txtDisplay` is always `None` not a `tk.Entry`. For more info read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66385069/11106801).

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo mistake, use `insertwidth` instead of `inserwidth`