# Please help me find the error in the code?

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, frame

I am trying to put a frame inside another frame in tkinter. Can someone explain why it isn't working? I am just starting to learn Tkinter.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import *
if __name__=="__main__":
  root = Tk()
  root.title("Sales")
  root.geometry("1440x855")
  root.resizable(0, 0)
  Label(root, text = 'Tax Invoice').pack(side = TOP, pady = 6)
  frame1 = Frame(root,bg="black",width=1400,height=780).pack()
  frame2 = Frame(frame1,bg="green",width=100,height=100).pack()
  top.mainloop()
```

Comment: `frame1` is always `None` not a `tkinter.Frame` object. For more info read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66385069/11106801)

Comment: change `frame1 = Frame(root,bg="black",width=1400,height=780).pack()` to `frame1 = Frame(root,bg="black",width=1400,height=780)` and `frame1.pack()`

Comment: 1st u need to change `top.mainloop()` change to `root.mainloop()` small spelling mistakes make big errors sometimes Case sensitive and spelling create problems in our code

Comment: What is "the error"? Is there any error message you can add to the question?

Comment: Please don't tag code questions with Editor/IDE, which has nothing to do with code errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```py
import tkinter as tk

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Sales")
    root.geometry("1440x855")
    root.resizable(False, False)

    label = tk.Label(root, text="Tax Invoice")
    label.pack(side="top", pady=6)

    frame1 = Frame(root, bg="black", width=1400, height=780)
    frame1.pack()
    frame2 = Frame(frame1, bg="green", width=100, height=100)
    frame2.pack()

    root.mainloop()
```

Basically applying what @Ramesh and I said in the comments.

Comment: I tried this code and it gave an error which was that the first frame did not appear on the screen.

Comment: @AMI Does the second frame appear on the screen?

Comment: Yes it does. But only the second frame appears.

Comment: @AMI my guess is that the first frame resizes to fit all of its child widgets (the second frame) and that is why you don't see it. Try adding `frame1.pack_propagate(False)` if you are still using `pack` inside it.